# how to put in a variable a command that reads line by line in iptables

Tags: iptables, bash

My file.txt:

```
# hex-strings
160301
160423
```

My variable:

```
abc=`sed '/^$/d; /#/d' file.txt`
```

and echo "$abc"

```
160301
160423
```

Perfect, but doesn't work in my iptables bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m string --hex-string "|$abc|" --algo bm -j DROP

iptables v1.6.1: Invalid hex char '
```

How do I fix the variable so that it runs well in iptables?

PD: If I apply the following rule it works fine:

```
for string in `sed '/^$/d; /#/d' file.txt`; do
   iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m string --hex-string "|$string|" --algo bm -j DROP
done
```

But it doesn't work with other rules. Example (with 2 files with strings "abc" and "def")

```
iptables -N mychain
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m string --hex-string "|$abc|" --algo bm -j mychain
iptables -A mychain -p tcp -m string --hex-string "|$def|" --algo bm -j DROP
```

**and that's why I need the variable**

Comment: You've got a newline in your variable which is not a valid hex character, you need to call iptables for each line in your variable instead of passing it the multi-line variable.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `sed '/^$/d; /#/d' file.txt | while read -r value; do iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m string --hex-string "|${value}|" --algo bm -j DROP; done`

Comment: that rule runs without errors, but it doesn't work